# Is it possible to make a column saying if a certain value is debit or credit?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm writing an ASP.NET program that imports data from an Excel file into a database. That Excel file has a column "Value in euro" (is it in portuguese so.. "Valor em EUR") and I want that during import of the file, the code creates a column in SQL Server named "Debit/credit". That column will define if the values in "Value in euro" are debit (negative) or credit (positive).

For example: table before the import:

```
Date of mov. Value in Euro 
12-09-2010   -5000
 3-19-2010   1928
```

Table after the import:

```
Date of mov. Value in Euro  Debit/Credit 
12-09-2010   -5000            Debit
 3-19-2010   1928             Credit
```

My code in asp.net:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    String strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HRD=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", excelConnection);

    excelConnection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", strConnection);

    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
    {
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Dados";
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Mov", "Data Mov.");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Valor", "Data Valor");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Descrição do Movimento" , "Descrição do Movimento");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Valor em EUR", "Valor em EUR");

        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    }

    excelConnection.Close();
}
```

Hope you guys understand what I meant... I am not finding nothing about this

Comment: Why not use a (persisted) computed column instead in your table? Then you don't need to insert the value, as it's calculated automatically.

Comment: What I should put in the formula?

Comment: Perhaps you want a computed column? Something like  `ALTER TABLE dbo.Dados ADD [Debit/Credit] AS CASE WHEN [Value in Euro] < 0 THEN 'debit ELSE 'credit' END;`